# .append() with Database

Tags: php, jquery, database, json

I'm trying to retrieve information from my database, and output it to my page. I'm able to hardcore it, so to show exactly what I want to be able to do is located here:

I'm not having any console errors in the javascript, but I am unable to append data to the list once it is clicked.

HTML & JS:

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../img/sd.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
<div id="body">
<div id="header"><h1><a href="#">Bookmarks</a></h1></div><!-- header -->
<iframe id="iFrame" name="iFrame"></iframe>
<div id="links"><ul id="accordion">

<li><div class="bookmarkTitle"><p><h4>CareerResources</h4></p></div></li><ul id="CareerResources">

</ul><li><div class="bookmarkTitle"><p><h4>CSS</h4></p></div></li><ul id="CSS">

</ul><li><div class="bookmarkTitle"><p><h4>JS</h4></p></div></li><ul id="JS">

</ul><li><div class="bookmarkTitle"><p><h4>JS: Jquery</h4></p></div></li><ul id="JS: jQuery">

</ul></div><!-- links end -->
</div><!-- body end -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $("#accordion > li").click(function(e){
        var catName=$(e.target).text();
        $.getJSON("get.php?catName=" + catName, function(data){ 
            if (data.data){ 
                $.each(data.data,function(index,value){ 
                    var url = value.URL; 
                    var title = value.title; 
                    var desc = value.desc; 
                    alert(catName);
                    $("#"+catName).append('<a href="'+url+'" target="iFrame"><div class="bookmark"><p><h3>'+title+'</h3><br />'+desc+'</p></div></a>'); 
                }); 
            } 
        });
    }); 
}); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
// retval: 0 - login ok, 1 - login failed, 2 - internal error
$json = array("retval" => 2, "data" => NULL, "debug" => "");

$catName=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['catName']);


$sql="SELECT * FROM linktb WHERE catName='$catName'";

$json['debug'] .= "SQL query was: ".$sql."\n";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    $json['debug'] .= "SQL query failed\n";
    $json['debug'] .= "Other output: ". ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    die(json_encode($json));
}
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count > 0){ 
$json['retval'] = 0; 
$json['data'] = array(); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
$json['data'][] = $row; 
} 
} else { 
$json['retval'] = 1; 
}

$json['debug'] .= "Other output: ". ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Insert generic plea to stop using `mysql_` functions here.

Comment: have you crossed checked the query in database?running successfully?

Comment: seems like catID is empty, try to output only catId to see is contents.

Comment: Where is `data` in `$.each(data,function(index,value){` defined? Also what the purpose of the `$.each`?

Comment: @sayannayas I inputted the query into the database and it does work.

Comment: @Musa I want it to output every line from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var catID=e.target.text();` Should be `var catID=$(e.target).text();` as `.text()` is a jQuery method.

If you want to iterate through the returned data you'll have to do it in the success function. Also from your php script you only output one row from your database.

```
if($count > 0){ 
    $json['retval'] = 0; 
    $json['data'] = array(); 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
        $json['data'][] = $row; 
    } 
} 
else { 
    $json['retval'] = 1; 
}
```

```
$.getJSON("get.php?catID=" + catID, function(data){ 
    if (data.data){ 
        $.each(data.data,function(index,value){ 
            var url = value.URL; 
            var title = value.title; 
            var desc = value.desc; 
            $("#"+catID).appendText('<a href="'+url+'" target="iFrame"><div class="bookmark"><p><h3>'+title+'</h3><br />'+desc+'</p></div></a>'); 
        }); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Updated, still providing no results though.

Comment: Updated the code, I've also uploaded what it looks like at the moment http://samaradionne.com/links2/ Why would that query only output one row? Or are you referring to my debugging.

Comment: @Phawkes you only fetch one row, see here `$json['data'] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);`

Comment: Ah I see, that being said, I'm not even getting one row's worth of results to show.

Comment: @Phawkes maybe because your query results in more than one row. You check the count and if it is 1 then you assign it.`$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){
    $json['retval'] = 0;
    $json['data'] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18889/discussion-between-phawkes-and-musa)